# Multi Scala version on one linux machine

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im working on several Scala projects and  liberties
Some of them work  on scala 2.10.x version and some of them work on the 2.11.X version .

My default $scala_home version is 2.11   so if a build something by default it will be built in the 2.11 version? **(thats true??)**

My main issue is with Apache Spark  and Kafka that are working fine with the 2.10.x version .

How are handling multi version dependency on one machine.

thanks,

miki

Comment: Well if they are separate SBT or Maven projects, you can configure the respective scala version in the respective build.sbt or pom.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I would not install a global Scala on the system, neither do I have a `$SCALA_HOME`. I think most people would recommend against it.

If you use a build tool like sbt, that will take care of applying the correct Scala version as required by your build definition. In sbt, you have a file `build.sbt` that contains an assignment `scalaVersion := "2.10.4"` or `scalaVersion := "2.11.5"` depending on which version you want to use. It keeps all the different Scala versions neatly separated in a cache directory and won't confuse them.